# Is there a way to conditionally compile based on the existence of a constant?

Tags: rust, conditional-compilation

The libc library defines a number of constants that can be passed as flags to `open()` such as `O_APPEND`, `O_CREAT`, etc. Some of these flags are only defined for certain OS targets. It'd be nice if there was a way to freely use `O_WHATEVER` in my code without worrying about whether it was actually defined in libc:

```
#[cfg(???)]
const O_WHATEVER = libc::O_WHATEVER;
#[cfg(not(???))]
const O_WHATEVER = 0;
```

It'd be nice if the `???` in my example above was some kind of `is_defined(libc::O_WHATEVER)`. Otherwise, I'd need to figure out all of the OS combinations in which `O_WHATEVER` is defined in libc and that'd be a real pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not as of Rust 1.41. [RFC 2523 — `cfg_version` and `cfg_accessible`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2523-cfg-path-version.html) introduces:

```
#[cfg(accessible(libc::O_WHATEVER))]
const O_WHATEVER = libc::O_WHATEVER;
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks =)